# Angular CLI + Webpack + i18n module integration

Tags: angularjs, angular, internationalization, webpack, angular-cli

I'm doing some tests with Angular CLI version 1.0.0-beta.19-3, which installs and uses Angular 2.1.0.  As you probably know, Angular-cli is using Webpack.

I tried to configure i18n module by following the procedure step by step in the [Angular 2 Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html).  The only hiccup is that the procedure is using a System.JS near the end for the XLIFF files merge.

I don't know how to handle that part of the procedure since Angular CLI is using Webpack, not systemJS.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Roger that.  I thought it was clear that I was not able to just follow step by step the procedure in the Official Angular documentation.  Updated question.

Comment: Try ng2-translate it worked for me. https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck there too and made something work which of course I would not consider 'final' but good enough for a proof of concept implementation:

1. No revision of the index.html necessary
2. SystemJS Text-Plugin not necessary (as we use Webpack and not SystemJS)

   Also we do not use an alternative for this plugin. (There is a plugin for webpack but unfortunately we cannot configure webpack currently with angular-cli) Instead we just re-write the .xlf-Files to .ts-Files manually. Each translation file looks something like this.

   Example messages.fr.ts:

   ```
   export const Translation = `
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
         <body>
            ...
        </body>
      </file>
   </xliff>
   `;
   ```
3. i18n-providers.ts has to be adapted like this:

   ```
   import { TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

   declare var System: any;

   interface TranslationFileContent {
     Translation: string;
   }

   export function getTranslationProviders(): Promise<Object[]> {

     // Set your locale here or get it from somewhere (e.g. localStorage)
     let locale: string = 'fr';

     const noProviders: Object[] = [];

     switch (locale) {
       case 'fr':
         return System.import('./messages.fr.ts')
           .then( (translations: TranslationFileContent ) => {
             return createProviders(translations, locale);
           })
           .catch(() => noProviders);
       // Add additional languages here
       default:
         return Promise.resolve(noProviders);
     }
   }

   function createProviders(translations: TranslationFileContent, locale: string) {
     return [
       { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations.Translation },
       { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
       { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale }
     ];
   }
   ```

   If you are surprised about the switch-case... Webpack will only bundle files which it can readout from the files so something like `System.import('./messages.' + locale + '.ts');` did not work for me. If you find something feel free to add this here as a comment.
4. main.ts is the same as in the angular cookbook for i18n

Regarding JiT (Just-in-Time) vs. AoT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation: The solution above is for **JiT**. I had another solution for AoT (which was actually simpler) but no solution (Project setup) that worked for both at he same time.

Hope this helped (and answer came not too late).

Comment: It's good to me. But is it possible to give us your solution in angular-cli (webpack) for aot, or at least aot only is fine.

Comment: I think I solved my problem. Below is the link that anyone who cares can reference to: https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358#.rzwmzdgjg

Comment: @Viet Yes, I also followed the link you posted for aot.

Comment: That's a very good alternative, I'm just changing the switch case to only get one return, any idea today about AoT if we dont have our hand onto the server ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but you can overcome the issue in nothing9's answer

You can avoid the switch statement by using System.import('raw-loader!.. for the raw xlf file. Then the code can look like this and you dont need to alter the generated xlf file.

```
var filename = 'app.' + locale + '.xlf';
return System.import('raw-loader!./i18n/' + filename)
.then((translations: TranslationFileContent) => {
  return [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale }
  ];
})
.catch(() => noProviders);
```

The key bit is the "raw-loader!" in the System.import call. Another way to achieve this would be to use rules in the webpack configuration file (webpack.config.js)

```
rules: [
{
"test": /.xlf/,
"loader": "promise-loader?es6-promise!raw-loader"
},
```

This will tell webpack to load all files with the xlf extension as raw.

Comment: Cool, I did not know about raw-loader. Thanks for that!